# Loading scene with AsyncOperation.progress jumps from 01f to 0.9f

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Using Unity 2018.1

When switching between scenes I show a canvas with a slider as a loading bar for the progress. But the slider is only showing .01f and .09f and it stays in .09 for a while until the scene loads.

Why isn't the slider showing the correct loading progress. What is wrong with the code.

```
public GameObject logoScreen;
public GameObject loadingScreen;
public Slider loadingSlider;

void Update ()
{
    // Logo Scene is Active
    if (logoScreen.activeInHierarchy == true)
    {
        //  Debug.Log("Logo Active");
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            logoScreen.SetActive(false);
            LoadScene(1);
        }
    }
}

AsyncOperation async;

public void LoadScene(int sceneNUM)
{
    StartCoroutine(LoadingScreen(sceneNUM));
}

IEnumerator LoadingScreen(int sceneNum)
{
    loadingScreen.SetActive(true);
    async = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneNum);
    async.allowSceneActivation = false;

    while (async.isDone == false)
    {
        loadingSlider.value = async.progress / 0.9f;
        if (async.progress == 0.9f)
        {
            loadingSlider.value = 1f;
            async.allowSceneActivation = true;
        }
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the slider to show?

Comment: the exact progress of the loading. it only shows the value of 0.1f at start and only 0.9f not the continuous flow from 0.2-0.8f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your code. Your scene is is loading quickly. This is because you didn't reference many resources so Unity loads from `0` to `9`. Scenes with few resource files will load quickly and you may not even see the loading time. Remember, I didn't say project, I said scene. If a resource file is placed in the project but is not referenced in a scene then it won't be loaded when that scene is loaded and this saves loading time.

To verify that this is is the problems, create an empty scene(scene 3). Attach components such as `AudioSource`, `VideoPlayer` and `RawImage` to GameObjects then assign audio, videos and images to them. Save it then change your code to load this scene 3. It should now take bit more time to load and `AsyncOperation.progress` will show values between `0` and `0.9`. *The more resources you reference, the more values you will see between `0` and `0.9`. and the more time it will take the scene to load*

Comment: thank you! and you said it runs everything through the progress that is referenced even deactivated gameobjects, correct?

Comment: Sorry. Can you rephrase that last question again?

Comment: just to know more in depth of whats being used as progress. You said anything referenced in the scene. I have a couple of gameobjects deacticated in the hierarchy, thats included in all?

Comment: It is still included even if it is deactivated because you'will have to activate that GameObject at some point. It makes no sense to not include them. Note that a simple GameObject does not make the game heavy. What makes it heavy is a GameObject that references a resources file.

Comment: not to familiar on how Unity would handle it’s code but I get it, anything that is referenced in the scene, including files. Thank you, I understand now